# Parameterize a parameterized type in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I am trying to type a decorator factory, whose basic structure isn't any real surprise:

```py
def make_wrapped_awaitable_or_aiter(
    awaitable_or_aiter, span_wrapper, ContextManager]
) -> AwaitableOrAIterT:
    if isinstance(awaitable_or_aiter, AsyncIterator):
        async def inner_iterable():
            with span_wrapper():
                async for v in awaitable_or_aiter:
                    yield v
        return inner_iterable()
    else:
        async def inner_awaitable():
            with span_wrapper():
                return await awaitable_or_aiter

        return inner_awaitable()


def decorator_factory(decorator_factory_arg1):
    def decorator(original_func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return awaitable_or_aiter(original_func(*args, **kwargs), some_contextmanager)
        return wrapped
    return decorator

@decorator_factory('foo')
def foobar('anything'):
    ...
```

The main twist here is that original_func will be always be either an async function or an async iterable.

I would like to type it in Python 3.8 so that mypy understands that the return type of the wrapped function will be the same as the return type of original_func, and that it will also be of the same async callable return type. I have this so far:

```py
AwaitableOrAIterT = TypeVar("AwaitableOrAIterT", Awaitable, AsyncIterator)

def make_wrapped_awaitable_or_aiter(
    awaitable_or_aiter: AwaitableOrAIterT, span_wrapper: Callable[[], ContextManager]
) -> AwaitableOrAIterT:
    if isinstance(awaitable_or_aiter, AsyncIterator):
        async def inner_iterable():
            with span_wrapper():
                async for v in awaitable_or_aiter:
                    yield v
        return inner_iterable()
    else:
        async def inner_awaitable():
            with span_wrapper():
                return await awaitable_or_aiter
        return inner_awaitable()

def decorator_factory(decorator_factory_arg1: str) -> Callable[[Callable[..., AwaitableOrAIterT]], Callable[..., AwaitableOrAIterT]]:
    def decorator(original_func: Callable[..., AwaitableOrAIterT]):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs) -> AwaitableOrAIterT:
            make_wrapped_awaitable_or_aiter(original_func(*args, **kwargs), some_contextmanager)
        return wrapped
    return decorator

@decorator_factory('foo')
async def foobar(some_arg: str) -> bool:
    return await some_query_typed_to_bool()
```

This allows the hinter to know that the async construct of "original_func" is what it expects (i.e. it infers `Awaitable`, and that something that calls `async with foobar()` is incorrect, and it also infers that trying to decorate a non-async function is incorrect), but it seems to specifically infer `Awaitable[Unknown]` rather than `Awaitable<bool>`, and I'm not entirely sure how to make it otherwise (presumably because it doesn't have any information about the return type from `inner_*` in `make_wrapped_awaitable_or_aiter`).

Essentially, I believe I need a way to parameterize AwaitableOrAIterT as a generic (using the return type of the Awaitable or AsyncIterator type), so I can annotate

```py
def make_wrapped_awaitable_or_aiter(
    awaitable_or_aiter: AwaitableOrAIterT[T], span_wrapper: Callable[[], ContextManager]
) -> AwaitableOrAIterT[T]:
    if isinstance(awaitable_or_aiter, AsyncIterator):
        async def inner_iterable() -> T:
            with span_wrapper():
                async for v in awaitable_or_aiter:
                    yield v
        return inner_iterable()
   ..etc..
```

but I don't know how this is done in 3.8.

Comment: I doubt that mypy supports this kind of type calculus.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled more and got what I needed. I have a decent guess what fixed it, but if anyone has corrections for me, they should add their own answer with the fuller picture. What I discovered is that

```py
AwaitableOrAIterT = TypeVar("AwaitableOrAIterT", Awaitable, AsyncIterator)
```

has the effect of obscuring the full type (so, e.g., it will type hint `Awaitable[<anything>]` as `Awaitable[Unknown]`). I instead did the following:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Awaitable, AsyncIterator, Union

T = TypeVar("T")
AwaitableOrAsyncIter = Union[Awaitable[T], AsyncIterator[T]]
AwaitableOrAIterT = TypeVar("AwaitableOrAIterT", bound=AwaitableOrAsyncIter)
```

I'm presuming that the TypeVar in the TypeAlias AwailtableOrAsyncIter makes it clear to mypy that the type of T in the generics in the union carries through transparently, although again, anyone who has more context should feel free to chime in.